# How can Insert Query Result into Temp Table or variable in AS400?

Tags: database, ibm-midrange

Like MSSQL there is provision for the query result into a temp table #var. In same way is there any solution or any kind of provision for db400 (IBMi, AS400).

Comment: in `SQL`, there is `declare global temporary table`.  Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-create-table) statement and the WITH DATA clause to create temporary tables in QTEMP from a result set.

```
CREATE TABLE QTEMP.VAR AS (SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) WITH DATA
```